# jQuery object from complete HTML document

Tags: jquery, dom

Is it possible to parse a complete HTML document as a complete jQuery object? When I try, e.g.

```
var $tmp = $("<html><head><title>title</title></head><body><p id='test'>test</p></body></html>");
console.log($tmp);
```

I get:

```
[+] [title, p#test] []
```

i.e. an array combining all of the head's children with all of the body's. Is it not possible to retain the structure, including the html, head, and body elements?

Comment: why are you wrapping the htmlwith $ sign???

Comment: @gov - That's how elements are created in jQuery.

Comment: @patrick , we can simply use a string concatination and do a .html at the end right.

Comment: @gov - I think OP wants DOM elements. The `.html()` method will give you a String.

Comment: Oddly enough, `$('<html />')` does produce a jQuery object containing an `html` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery strips out html and body as there can only be one html and body in a document.  Brian's answer is the closest you can get, but only on non IE browser as IE don't parse non html tag.

For example:

```
var test = "<test>This is it</test>";
alert($(test).html());  // display This is it in non IE browser (working in 8-9?).
```

EDIT:
How about replacing html and body with div class=html/body?

```
var test = "<html><body><div>this is a test</div></body></html>";
test = test.replace(/(\/body|\/html)/i, "\/div")
           .replace(/html/i, "div class='html'")
           .replace(/body/i, "div class='body'");
console.log($(test));
```

Comment: You can certainly create additional `html` and `body` elements in the **DOM**, at least in some implementations (only tested in WebKit, using `document.createElement`). You can even append them to other elements (`element.appendChild`). jQuery strips these out because it's absurdly rare in common use cases that developers will want to do this, but quite common that they'll want to just dump a server response from an Ajax call into a `div` somewhere.

Comment: @eylidlessness, you are right, I tested in FF to append a second body to html (not inside a div) and the second body is displayed, but in IE, the second body is not displayed. I guess, I'll stick with the "proper" html construct :).

Answer (score 0):

I think jQuery uses the browser's native `innerHTML` to create the elements in that situation. As such, some browsers allow it, others don't. I think it will work in Firefox, but not IE.

Perhaps you could try piecing it together using the native `document.createElement()`. Not sure if it will work.

Comment: Thanks, Patrick. No luck in Firefox. What I'm really trying to do is just use jQuery's core functionality to parse an HTML document fetched via AJAX. It looks like I'll have to do a BIT more work myself ...

Comment: @Bobby - You're welcome. Yeah, likely it will take a little manual parsing, depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

A kind of hack would be to string replace the 'html' nodes with something other than the word 'html'.

```
var tmp = '<html><head><title>title</title></head><body><p id="test">test</p></body></html>';
tmp = tmp.replace(/html/g, 'html1');
console.log($(tmp));
```

I'm not sure I really *like* this idea though...